# displaying button only for the checkbox checked. js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox which onclick displays a button, and only one check box can be clicked at a time, however; when I click checkbox its displaying button for all rows. and also when I click one checkbox and at the sametime if I check next checkbox it keeps displaying the button(for the last checkbox checked) even though its not checked now.im sorry if I am not clear please look test code below for more information.  only one button shoud appear for the checkbox checked and if its unchecked button should not appear.any help will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".your", function() {
   $('.your').not(this).prop('checked', false); //this will make only on checkbox to be checked 
   $('.deleteButton').toggle(this.checked);
  });
```

```css
.testtable{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="testtable">
</th>
<tr>testcolumn</tr>
</th>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox"  class="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">
<input type="button"  class="deleteButton" style="display:none">  
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox"  class="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">
<input type="button"  class="deleteButton" style="display:none">  
</td></tr>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox"  class="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">
<input type="button"  class="deleteButton" style="display:none">  
</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both checkbox and button are in the same level, you can use `$.siblings()` to toggle only that. But you have to first hide the others. A good practice would be caching the button by assigning them to a variable for better performance on a micro level.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".your", function() {

   $('.your').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
   // hide all 
   $('.deleteButton').hide();
   // show only this
   $(this).siblings('.deleteButton').toggle(this.checked);

});
```

```css
.testtable{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="testtable">
</th>
<tr>testcolumn</tr>
</th>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox"  class="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">
<input type="button"  class="deleteButton" style="display:none">  
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox"  class="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">
<input type="button"  class="deleteButton" style="display:none">  
</td></tr>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox"  class="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">
<input type="button"  class="deleteButton" style="display:none">  
</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.deleteButton').show();` makes the button near the checkbox show up no matter what is the state of the checkbox (checked or unchecked). You should **toggle** its visibility.

Comment: Adam thx for your effort, but there is still one issue on your code. when I click the checkbox and uncheck it the button does not go away(keeps showing). please help